# how to store radio button value in sessionStorage with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage, sessionstorage

I have radio button in my navbar and I want to store its value for one session or I can say it automatically retains the same value as user visits different pages of website but resets when browser or tab is closed. What I found is sessionStorage and I tried it but unfortunately its not working, here is my code

```
  <lab
```

```js
  console.log($('[type=radio]').length);
  
        $("#option1").click(function() {
          console.log('I am inside radio type'+this.value);
          sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value);
        });

        $("#option2").click(function() {
          console.log('I am inside radio type'+this.value);
          sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value);
        });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons"> -->
  <!-- <label class="btn btn-secondary active"> -->
  <input type="radio" value="shop" name="option" id="option1">option1
  <!-- </label> -->
  <!-- <label class="btn btn-secondary"> -->
  <input type="radio" value="product" name="option" id="option2">option2
  <!-- </label> -->
  <!-- </div> -->
```

el class="btn btn-secondary active">
       Option1
      
      
       Option2

In script what I tried is

```
$('[type=radio]').click(function() {
        var value = $('[name="option"]').val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('option',value);
});

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('option'));
```

Its only printing option1 every time and is it the right way what I want to achieve ?

Comment: `this` will be the option you clicked.  There is no need to look it up.  Just reference `this.value`  `sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value);`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I found that problem is on clicking the radio button function is not  running, i tried this
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        console.log('I am inside radio type');
        sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value);
    });
on clicking on radio button nothing is printing on consol

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to bind to them before they exist in the page.

Comment: I am unable to understand, on clicking the radio buttons why nothing is printing on console? Did something wrong with above code ?

Comment: If the input fields do not exist in the DOM at the time that you perform `$('[type=radio]')`, it will not find them to bind the event handler on them.  They must exist when you run that operation.

Comment: yes, thanks sir when I tried with another test button it worked, but now what is the solution for that ? I am using django including the form from another html

Comment: You could try sticking the logic inside a document ready to delay it until the document has loaded.  Take a look at Abhilash's answer below.  The `$(function(){ ... })` is a short hand document ready

Comment: sorry to say sir but its not working sir.

Comment: Are these elements static on the page, or are you dynamically creating them with javascript?

Comment: yes they are static only but I am including them from another html

Comment: So if you put `console.log($('[type=radio]').length);` right before you do your click binding, you should see it print out a # > 0

Comment: its showing 2, when I tried by getting element by id it worked -     $("#option1").click(function() {
          console.log('I am inside radio type');)};

Comment: ok, that doesn't make sense.  Would you do me a favor?  Edit your question and hit Ctrl+M.  This will bring up the on site editor.  See if you can replicate the issue here.

Comment: by id its saving cookies also but i need to define it for both, is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

The type value needs to be formatted as a string with quotes around it, like below:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { 
    console.log('I am inside radio type'); 
    sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value); 
});
```

And if you're loading these buttons dynamically/after loading the script, you can attach the listener to the document object instead:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() { 
    console.log('I am inside radio type'); 
    sessionStorage.setItem('option', this.value); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click event store the value of checked radio button as follows,

```
 $(function() {
         alert(sessionStorage.getItem('option'));
         $('[type=radio]').click(function() {
                  alert(this.value);           sessionStorage.setItem('option',this.value);
          });    
    });
```